# Are the gods of Theros considered creatures in my hand?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For example if I have one god of Theros in my hand like [Xenagos, God of Revels](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Xenagos%2C%20God%20of%20Revels) Can I play it using a [Quicksilver Amulet](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Quicksilver%20Amulet) even though I dont have enough devotion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still play it with the Amulet. On Xenagos' page:

> The type-changing ability that can make the God not be a creature functions only on the battlefield. It’s always a creature card in other zones, regardless of your devotion to its color.